# How to use SWFUPLOAD for iPhone Http server by deusty design

Tags: iphone, http, swfupload

I have an iPhone http server running on my iPhone but this supports just a single file upload and without and progress bar. I read that SWF upload can do this for me but I dont know if it works or not as the iPhone http server doesnot support server side scripting.
I want to know if i can use SWF upload in for my cliet side....and how?
Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

swfupload requires a server side script to accept the incoming file data, so if your http server doesn't support that, the simple answer is "no".

What are you actually trying to do though? It sounds slightly crazy ;-)

Comment: well it is..but i got so frustrated while searching for a scheme to upload multiple files on the server without any server side scripts..that i ended up asking this question :)
so here i go again... (iphone http server supports only PUT GET and POST methods)
Is there a way to upload multiple file without server side script?

Comment: jAmi: “iphone http server”? It seems unlikely that Apple would have bundled Apache on every iPhone. You should post this comment as a separate question, and clarify in it what you mean by “iphone http server”.